# Making a Selenium version of ab

Tags: selenium, load-testing

I would like to use Selenium instead of `ab` for load testing my server, so I created a selenium script that requests the same url over and over again. There would, however, be some information that could help replicate `ab` better:

1)
Does requesting the same page in two different tabs count as two concurrent requests?

2) How can I use selenium to get information such as the "Resource Size" of a request and count the number of Requests per Second? (I realize that when requesting a page, Selenium uses a real browser, so downloading a page and all of its content would be separate requests.)

3) Also, is there a way to retrieve the number of concurrent connections?

I am currently using the [bindings for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), but am willing to use any language with selenium bindings if I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO, none of what you want to do is particularly easy using WebDriver (aka Selenium 2).

1) The same page in two different tabs will likely utilize the browser's cache, so it will not have the same effect as two real users on different machines hitting the page. You can control the cache operation of some browsers, but maybe not well enough for your purposes.

2 & 3) WebDriver operates against the DOM, which AFAIK does not have access to the low-level network stats you are looking for.